# Use sussy with laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, susy, laravel-mix

Can anybody help me in using susy with laravel project?

I have installed all the dependencies using `npm install`
and followed [these steps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/susy#using-webpack) to install susy.

this is my webpack.mix.js file

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
       resolve: {
           modules:[
               loaders: [
                   {
                     test: /\.scss$/,
                     loader: 'style!css!sass'
                   }
               ]
           ]           
       }
   });
```

I am getting this error when I run `npm run watch`

[image: susy error]

Comment: What version of Susy do you have installed. Note that [Susy3 does not include any mixins](http://oddbird.net/2017/06/28/susy3/) – so this error could be caused by upgrading Susy, even if the laravel setup is correct.

Comment: Yes. I intsalled susy3 and did not know about the updates. Thanks for your help!